# Getting PermissionError when uploading a dataframe to bigquery existing table when using pandas_gbq.to_gbq

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm uploading a pandas dataframe to bigquery using the next command:

```
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df, table_id, table_schema=schema_,if_exists= 'append', chunksize = 100)
```

As you can see I'm uploading the data in chunks.

at the start, the process is working and it is uploading chunks of the data to the desired table, but at some point (after 255 iterations), I get the next error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\AMIT~1.SHR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp1e4wr6vl_job_88b5419e.csv
```

I couldn't succeed to locate this CSV on my computer and don't know what is it.

The full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/amit.shreiber/PycharmProjects/churn/churn_metric.py", line 498, in <module>
    load_to_bq_gbq( months_retention_df)
  File "C:\Users\amit.shreiber\PycharmProjects\churn\BQ_functions.py", line 48, in load_to_bq_gbq
    pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df, table_id, table_schema=schema_,if_exists= 'append', chunksize = 100)
  File "C:\Users\amit.shreiber\Anaconda3\envs\churn\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.py", line 1093, in to_gbq
    connector.load_data(
  File "C:\Users\amit.shreiber\Anaconda3\envs\churn\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\gbq.py", line 573, in load_data
    for remaining_rows in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\amit.shreiber\Anaconda3\envs\churn\lib\site-packages\tqdm\std.py", line 1178, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\amit.shreiber\Anaconda3\envs\churn\lib\site-packages\pandas_gbq\load.py", line 79, in load_chunks
    client.load_table_from_dataframe(
  File "C:\Users\amit.shreiber\Anaconda3\envs\churn\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\client.py", line 2579, in load_table_from_dataframe
    os.remove(tmppath)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\AMIT~1.SHR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp1e4wr6vl_job_88b5419e.csv'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but when I choose a bigger chunk size(1000) it worked.